Same morphism between more couples of objects?
I was studying elementary category theory when a question came to my mind.
Is it possible in a category for the same "entity" to be a morphism between more than one couple of objects (i.e. to admit different couples domain-codomain)?
I do not explicitly refer to a single definition since I'm studying from notes, where this question is not addressed explicitly: by the definition given there, the answer to my question seems to be positive. Nevertheless, after some pages, it makes the assertion that, if the objects of a category do not form a set, then the arrows do not, proving that by saying that the identities are as much as the objects, so since different objects have different identity arrows, and as a consequence the collection of arrows cannot be a set. So the answer now seems to be negative.
I've also read here that somehow it does not make sense to conceive equality between morphisms having different domain and codomain. So in categories it is involved another "local" definition of equality different from the one of the entities involved, rather than assuming (more or less explicitly) that the hom-sets (viz. hom-classes) are disjoint? A related question could be if the same entity could be both an object and a morphism. How equality would be dealt with then?
In the answers, a survey of the definitions can be useful, but a conceptual explanation of the possible choices may be more.

Most axiomatizations of category theory either require explicilty that distinct Hom collections be pairwise disjoint, or include (class) functions "domain" and "codomain" that would force them to be pairwise disjoint.

It is difficult to understand what you are saying, as your sentences are not grammatically coherent. After much thought, I think I know what you are trying to get at: Are you tying to suggest a notion of a category where the hom-sets potentially overlap?

@kabelabel I've tried to make it clearer. Anyway, yes, that's was I was meaning.

This depends heavily on what foundations you're working in. In materialist foundations such as set theory, it may happen that two morphisms $f : a \to b$ and $g : c \to d$ are encoded by the same set, but this is of course completely inessential. In structuralist foundations like (homotopy) type theory, $a \to b$ and $c \to d$ are different types so you cannot directly compare $f$ and $g$ for equality.

Ah. Well, in that case, this is usually not allowed for in category theory, but I don't think it'd actually change anything if it was allowed for. No theorem I know of in category theory explicitly relies on the disjointness of hom-sets.

@kabelabel So, just by saying, the assertion in my third paragraph is not a theorem of category theory?

The fact that different objects have different identity arrows? No, that is not a "theorem" of category theory, tho some authors explicitly prohimit overlapping hom-sets, so I guess it'd be true by definition there. If we allowed for overlapping hom-sets, the axioms only say that each object has an identity, it says nothing abount different objects having different ones.
Luckily for us, it doesn't change anything in terms of category-theoretical properties either way, which is why most authors don't even tend to bother with deliniating between these cases.

Note that even if the same set happens to code for $\mathrm{id}a : a \to a$ and $\mathrm{id}b : b \to b$, they would not be completely identified, since they have different domains and codomains. In other words, the "set of all morphisms" in a category (assuming such a thing exists) is $\Sigma{a, b : \mathrm{Ob}} (a \to b)$, not $\bigcup{a, b : \mathrm{Ob}} (a \to b)$.
